# Can't retrieve data from api

Tags: javascript

I'm using the NY Times top stories API to get some information about the top articles however no information is printing in the console. I have no errors but nothing prints so perhaps I have not retrieved the information properly.
Here is the JSON data from the api: [image]

NOTE: Someone on my old question told me to make a new question because they had already solved a different issue on there. This actual problem wasn't solved on there so it's not a duplicate.
JavaScript

```
const url = 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/science.json?api-key=' /* here was API key */;
function setup() {
    $.getJSON("https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/science.json?api-key=*here was the API key*", gotData);
}

function gotData(data) {
    console.log(data.results[0].title)
}
```

Comment: We need a [mcve]. What library is `loadJSON` from?

Comment: 1. Maybe `loadJSON` is missing (the source library is not linked). 2. Maybe `setup()` isn't called. If I had to guess.

Comment: Please show us loadJSON and remove noCanvas if it is not relevant

Comment: [Your code works](https://jsfiddle.net/782wf4p6/) assuming everything's called in the right order, and `loadJSON` exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works better

```js
fetch('https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/science.json?api-key=yourApiKey')
  .then((resp) => resp.json()) 
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data.results[0].title)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of libraries that allow you to have a simple code to retrieve data from web server.

Like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) for example an Promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js
or using [JQuery Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or even javascript [XMLHttpRequest](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) and [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) depends on your need.

Here is a quick and simple example using axios.

```js
const url = 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/science.json?api-key=yourApiKey'

axios.get(url)
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Fetch does this identically without any library. See my example

Comment: @mplungjan yes sure forgot to mention sorry you're right